# keyboard shortcut to access emacs gui top menu in linux

Tags: user-interface, emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

what are the keys to access file/edit/options/buffers/tools/help menu bar items? There are a zillion emacs key combos and only the mouse can get to those. :?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the GUI version, you should be able to use <kbd>F10</kbd> to access the menu, and the cursor keys to navigate. You can bind a key to it with the function `menu-bar-open`.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite the same since you said "gui", but you can also use <kbd>M-`</kbd> to go through a menu selection dialog in the minibuffer.  This keystroke is also beneficial when running emacs in a terminal.

Comment: So, so cute. I have to go into text shell because in ubuntu, in X, that combination switches between windows by default. But it's crazy good fun, like working on an old dos or pdp console. Thanks (look at my rep and that's my excuse for cheap words).

Comment: This command is part of the library tmm :  text-mode access to menu-bar.